# Duplicate rows CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im encourting a problem with my "add" function on the "subscriptions" model.
1% of the registerations is duplicated(2 or even up to 5 times) for some reason.

this is the code im using:

```
public function add($service, $phone, $sushi_subscription_id, $answer_id, $affiliate_id, $ip, $query, $invite_type, $invite_msg_id)
{
    $this->db->set('service_id', $service->id);
    $this->db->set('sushi_service_id', $service->sushi_service_id);
    $this->db->set('phone', $phone);

    if ($sushi_subscription_id)
    {
        $this->db->set('sushi_subscription_id', $sushi_subscription_id);
    }

    $this->db->set('answer_id', $answer_id);
    if ($affiliate_id)
    {
        $this->db->set('affiliate_id', $affiliate_id);
    }

    $this->db->set('added', 'NOW()', FALSE);

    $this->db->set('active', 1);
    $this->db->set('ip', $ip);

    $this->db->set('query', $query);

    if ($invite_type)
    {
        $this->db->set('invite_type', $invite_type);
    }

    if ($invite_msg_id)
    {
        $this->db->set('invite_msg_id', $invite_msg_id);
    }

    return ($this->db->insert($this->_table_name)) ? $this->db->insert_id() : FALSE;
}
```

any idea how I could avoid this from happaning? the row is exactly the same.
service_id, phone, active, even the added date!

Comment: If it is not duplication ALL the time, then your issue is most likely with the code that calls this function.  Please post the controller code that calls the `add` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not totally irrelevant but it is very useful to build up your own generic functions or modules that serves your requirements. Here is check_duplicate function working as generic function checking duplicate data entry in DB. Here is the function

```
function _check_duplicate($table_name,$param)
{
    $row_count=$this->db->get_where($table_name,$param)->num_rows();
    if(count($row_count>0))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

here is how you call the function;

```
if($this->_check_duplicate('table_name',array('param1'=>$param1,'param2'=>$param2)))
{
    // redirect to some page
}
else
{
    // do something, insert or update
}
```

for parameters, you can pass as many parameters as required. this function can be generic in a controller or can be part of generic module. It depends how you use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will help you.....

```
//model
function add($data){
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata("message", "Record successfully created.");
}


//in your controller
 function create(){
        $data = array( 'service_id'             => $this->input->post('service_id'),
                        'sushi_service_id'      => $this->input->post('sushi_service_id'),
                        'phone'                 => $this->input->post('phone'),
                        'sushi_subscription_id' => $this->input->post('sushi_subscription_id'),
                        'answer_id'             => $this->input->post('answer_id'),
                        'affiliate_id'          => $this->input->post('affiliate_id'),
                        ''                      => $this->input->post(), // and so on and so on just like that copy and do that
                        //add more here
                        );
        $this->"model name"->add($data);
    }


//view
<form action="<?=site_url('controller_name/create');?>" method = "POST">//the word create is the function name and dont forget to change the controller name
    <input type="text" name="service_id"/>
    <input type="text" name="sushi_service_id"/>
    <input type="text" name="phone"/>
    //and so on and so on....just copy and do like that
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```